# Show growl when login or register

Tags: php, jquery, growl

How can I display a growl pop-up when someone login or register ? 
I tried with 10 sec COOKIE, but I don't know how to echo that growl ? Can somebody help ?

This is the growl: http://ksylvest.github.io/jquery-growl/

Comment: Can you provide your `code` that you have so far.

Comment: I don't have a `special code`. All I have are those files from growl and `<script>` too and I'm using an IF to check if I have that cookie. Cookies work , growl doesn't !

Answer (score 0):

Just giving some points I guess you have 2 options
1. When they login/register successfully refresh the page and have

```
$.growl({ title: "Growl", message: "The kitten is awake!" });
```

In your document.ready

2. Use ajax to register/login and once complete on the success use the same code

Comment: What browser are you using? I note that the example uses jquery 2.0 - which doesn't work on older browsers (ie6-8 I think), what errors do you get?

Comment: Well, kinda at a loss - I don't use the software myself so no ideas. Best guess - is if there are no javascript errors then you issue might lie with css. I would have a basic page - make sure it works there. Just simple body/html. Only other thing that it could be is are you linking to the javascript/css - no 404 errors. Has the application downloaded correctly - check the files. Sorry for being basic here but I'm out of ideas.